# Remove a dynamic form field JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

I'm relatively new to JS and HTML and was following this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaeCSh7YJDM&t=422s ) in order to turn a select box and input box into a dynamic form field in order to add as many of them as needed with an add button. The add button works perfectly, though after implementing the same code as in the video, the remove button does not function and I can't quite figure out why. I've gone back and rewatched and cross checked the videos code and mine though can't seem to see what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the section of code I have.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row" id = "addF" >
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 form-control-label">
                    Label
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="xxxx" name="yyyyy" required>
                        <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="" style="display:none;">Select Fact</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id=vvvv" name="zzzz" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1">
                <input type="button" id="add_fact()" onClick="addFact()" value="+">
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var i =1;

        function addFact(){
            i++;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '<label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 form-control-label">Label '+i+'</label><div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"> <select class="form-control" id="xxxx'+i+'" name="yyyy_'+i+'" required><option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="" style="display:none;">Select Fact</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vvvv" name="zzzz_'+i+'" required></div><div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1"><input type="button" id="add_fact()" onClick="addFact()" value="+"></div><div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1"><input type="button" value="-" onClick="removeFact(this)"></div>';
            document.getElementById('addF').appendChild(div);

        function removeFact(div) {
            document.getElementById('addF').removeChild(div.parentNode);
            i--;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: if you are using jquery use "live" method to delete dynamic field. like this: $("button").live("click", function(){
    $(".col-sm-3").remove();
});

Comment: For starters: check your html as you have various " missing, both in your html as in the js `div.innerHTML` strings.  Create your code on eg. jsfiddle.net and check your console for errors.

Comment: EDIT: I may have been wrong about the js... just carefully check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "removeFact" function you are not receiving the div element; as you are calling it with "this" as parameter, you receive the button element, so to fix it, you must call the function like this

```
onClick="removeFact(this.parentNode)"
```

or change your function this way

```
function removeFact(button) {
    document.getElementById('addF').removeChild(button.parentNode.parentNode);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the bottom one worked for me! I'll have to look more into "this" and adding in the other .parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go one level deeper.

Try this :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var i =1;

        function addFact(){
            i++;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '<label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 form-control-label">Label '+i+'</label><div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"> <select class="form-control" id="xxxx'+i+'" name="yyyy_'+i+'" required><option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="" style="display:none;">Select Fact</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vvvv" name="zzzz_'+i+'" required></div><div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1"><input type="button" id="add_fact()" onClick="addFact()" value="+"></div><div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1"><input type="button" value="-" onClick="removeFact(this)"></div>';
            document.getElementById('addF').appendChild(div);
}


         function removeFact(div) {
                document.getElementById('addF').removeChild(div.parentNode.parentNode);
                i--;
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked I'll take a look into the .parentNode as I'm not entirely sure why it needs to go one deeper or where specifically it was going with my old code.